# FastReport DrillDown Group Totals

Tags: sql, delphi, fastreport

I have a report that has 2 groups and i need the main group to show the second groups totals both groups are drill down groups, i tried using the Fast Report example in user manual but it throws me an error cannot convert null into ... but i know that the values in total fields are all there here is a preview of my design and where i want the totals:

[image]

any ideas on how to achieve this?

**What i tried already**

1. Fast Report 4 User manual http://goo.gl/tsqM6w didn't work

Comment: Are you sure you've set the report to multi-pass as detailed in the manual?

Comment: Yes I am sure, i tried both ways the simple way and the long way neither work for me :/